# how to check null values in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, foreach, view

I keep getting null exceptions when iterating over my foreach loop and I think it is because they
way I am trying to check, iterate and skip over the nulll values is incorrects. Basically when it doesnt fine "New" it throws an exception.

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> NewRequisitionsEntryList()
        {
            //var requisitions = _repositoryWrapper.Requisition.GetAllNewRequisitions();
            //UserInformation UserInformation = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            var newReqList = _context.Requisition.OrderByDescending(r => r.Status.Equals("New")).ToList();

            foreach (var reqList in newReqList ?? Enumerable.Empty<Requisition>())
            {
                UserInformation identityUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
                var departmentId = _context.Department.Where(x => x.DepartmentName == identityUser.Department).FirstOrDefault();
                var userDepartmentId = departmentId.DepartmentId;
                if (departmentId.DepartmentId == reqList.DepartmentId)
                {
                    if (_context.ProcessStepLog.Where(d => d.RequistionId == reqList.RequisitionId).FirstOrDefault().ProcessStepName == "New")
                    {
                        CurrentStepName = _context.ProcessStepLog.Where(d => d.RequistionId == reqList.RequisitionId).FirstOrDefault().ProcessStepName;
                        requistionsNew.Add(new NewRequistionModel()
                        {
                            RequistionNo = reqList.RequisitionNo,
                            RequisitionTitle = reqList.RequisitionTitle,
                            DateCreated = reqList.DateCreated,
                            ProcessStepName = CurrentStepName,
                            RequestedBy = reqList.QueriesEmail,
                        });
                    }
                   
                }
            }
            
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("workspace");

            });
            ViewData["requistionsNew"] = requistionsNew;
            return View(newReqList);
     
        }
```

Comment: You check for `null` inside a loop in exactly the same way as you check for `null` outside a loop. You don't have to wonder where the problem is. Debug your code and you can find out exactly where, how and why it is failing. If you still can't work out how to fix it, you need to provide that information to us.

Comment: Its breaking on the second if clause on the line that has the where statement so I have to check  that , thanks

Comment: OT, there's no need to call `Where` and `FirstOrDefault`. You can just call the latter as it will accept the same filter as `Where`.

Comment: put it in a variable first instead of querying inside your if statement. That will make checking for NULL much easier.

Answer (score 0):

> Its breaking on the second if clause on the line that has the where statement

So you mean the second if clause makes error. We can analysis that firstly you use the `_context` before the if clause without any error, so it will not be null for the context. Then we can see you use `FirstOrDefault` which can get the model data, here can receive null value. Null value is acceptbale but if you want to get the property of the null object, it will throw exception.

You can simply use `?` to avoid null exception:

```
_context.ProcessStepLog.Where(d => d.RequistionId == reqList.RequisitionId).FirstOrDefault()?.ProcessStepName;
```

Or change the if clause:

```
var model = _context.ProcessStepLog.Where(d => d.RequistionId == reqList.RequisitionId).FirstOrDefault();
if (model !=null && model .ProcessStepName == "New")
```

Suggestions:

Actually debugging code is the most efficient way to find out the error and know how to modify. You need set the breakpoint to your action and quick watch the line which makes error, step by step to find where is the real error. For example, right-click and choose quick watch, then in the search bar type the `_context.ProcessStepLog` to check the value or `Results View`. If it contains value, then type `Where(d => d.RequistionId == reqList.RequisitionId).FirstOrDefault()` to check it. Step by Step.....

Refer to:

[Use breakpoints in the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2022)

[Watch variables with Watch windows and QuickWatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows?view=vs-2022)